# Docker Celery configuration - For Django/React/Redis/Celery project. No Celery logo and background task log appearing

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, redis, celery

I have created a project github repository that has Docker, Django, React, Redis, Celery:
https://github.com/axilaris/dockerize-django-react-celery-redis. My goal is to get celery working correctly with the logo appearing and background task log prints.

This is based from this Docker - React and Django example tutorial code:
https://github.com/dotja/authentication_app_react_django_rest

And trying to use Docker - Celery & Redis from this tutorial code:
https://github.com/veryacademy/docker-mastery-with-django/tree/main/Part-4%20Django%20Postgres%20Redis%20and%20Celery <-- Part 4 tutorial for Celery & Redis

Here is the docker-compose.yaml for the redis & celery part:

```
# Redis
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    container_name: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

# celery
  celery:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./backend
    command: celery -A backend worker -l DEBUG
    volumes:
      - .:/django
    container_name: celery  
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - backend
```

here is how I implemented the background tasks in user_api/tasks.py (https://github.com/axilaris/dockerize-django-react-celery-redis/blob/main/backend/user_api/tasks.py)

```
in backend/user_api/tasks.py

from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

from celery import shared_task
import logging

@shared_task
def add(x, y):
    logging.debug("XXX add")
    return x + y
```

my project should work very simply by running:

```
 docker-compose build
 docker-compose up
```

However, there is no celery logo (1) and I dont see the logs print on the background process (2). I think it is executing as result.ready returns. But I want these 2 for completeness. (eventhough result.ready maybe be working with celery executing background task)

It did not print this celery logo. (you can check the full log prints for docker-compose up - https://gist.github.com/axilaris/a2776fc8f39e53bbc93e0d7a4e0ba0f5):

```
celery       |  -------------- celery@b755a7cdba8d v5.3.6 (emerald-rush)
celery       | --- ***** ----- 
celery       | -- ******* ---- Linux-6.6.12-linuxkit-aarch64-with 2024-03-02 20:48:06
celery       | - *** --- * --- 
celery       | - ** ---------- [config]
celery       | - ** ---------- .> app:         core:0xffff9bbd7550
celery       | - ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://redis:6379//
celery       | - ** ---------- .> results:     redis://redis:6379/
celery       | - *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 10 (prefork)
celery       | -- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
celery       | --- ***** ----- 
celery       |  -------------- [queues]
celery       |                 .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
```

and here is how I execute the background task, but there is no log prints in django logs on the background task. (you can find the full log prints https://gist.github.com/axilaris/a2776fc8f39e53bbc93e0d7a4e0ba0f5)

```
>>> % docker exec -it backend_container sh 
>>> /app # python manage.py shell
>>> Python 3.9.18 (main, Jan 27 2024, 07:18:02) 
>>> [GCC 13.2.1 20231014] on linux
>>> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> (InteractiveConsole)
>>> from user_api.tasks import add
>>> result = add.delay(2, 2)
>>> result.ready
<bound method AsyncResult.ready of <AsyncResult: 9046dd90-f44d-4eba-9881-acc0fbc4278a>>
```

My goal is to see that celery logo print above and to verify in the django logs that the background process is executed just like in (https://youtu.be/oBQxFn1CDno?si=58ZRfLZeuCC8fz01&t=1204 at 20:04).

UPDATE (based on Sujay)

- 2 changes:

  - mounting django and celery in [docker-compose.yaml](https://github.com/axilaris/dockerize-django-react-celery-redis/blob/test1/docker-compose.yaml)
  - change to CMD to run ["/app/entrypoint.sh"] in django [DockerFile](https://github.com/axilaris/dockerize-django-react-celery-redis/blob/test1/backend/Dockerfile)
- result (see [logs here](https://gist.github.com/axilaris/8bc514ed9ec3b0da4a06afda1180695b)):

  - celery logo appears ! I think its running well
  - django container exit due to entrypoint.sh permission denied. I even tried with giving permission but doesnt work.

This looks promising but django container error which makes it I cant run action no.2 which is the background task

- I check in this code [here](https://github.com/axilaris/dockerize-django-react-celery-redis/tree/test1) in a separate branch if someone wants to check.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  A link to your repository is helpful, but it can't be the only way you're including key details like your Dockerfile.  If the worker container doesn't print the Celery banner, what does it print?  The `volumes:` mount looks like it might be overwriting your application source code, which can lead to various inconsistencies; does deleting it help?

Comment: I'ved added a bit more code details on the task code and log prints from docker-compose up and the separate container calling to execute the background task https://gist.github.com/axilaris/a2776fc8f39e53bbc93e0d7a4e0ba0f5. by the way, its fairly simple to spin off the docker with docker-compose build and up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I understand is you want celery to get start working on

```
docker-compose build
```

Firstly you need to understand how docker works with django and celery:
so your docker services

1. Backend
2. celery

both need to be on same shared volume.

now when you copy django data to docker container
see you docker file for **backend** it copies to app dir
command in docker -

```
COPY . /app
```

and in you docker compose file you have volume conf as

```
 - .:/django
```

so  all you dirs needs to be streamlined

first change your docker file as follows

```
    FROM python:3.9-alpine

RUN apk update && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY ./entrypoint.sh .

CMD ["/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

then change you docker-compose file to

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  # Redis
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    container_name: redis
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'

  backend:
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app
      - static:/static
    env_file:
      - .env
    build:
      context: ./backend
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    container_name: backend_container

  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
    volumes:
      - frontend:/app/build
    container_name: frontend_container
  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static:/static
      - frontend:/var/www/frontend
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - backend
      - frontend

  # celery
  celery:
    restart: always
    build: ./backend
    command: celery -A backend worker -l info
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app
    container_name: celery
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - backend

volumes:
  static:
  frontend:
```

so all I changed was docker file last line to
CMD["command"]
so that it not executed on build
and
adjusted volumes in docker-compose to point to same volume as build

[your expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqdum.png)

I suggest you to watch this 2 videos

1)https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mScd-Pc_pX0&ab_channel=LondonAppDeveloper

2)https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EfWa6KH8nVI&ab_channel=PriyanshuGupta

Comment: oh you got it working, i'll try it soon!

Comment: I see now the celery logo https://gist.github.com/axilaris/8bc514ed9ec3b0da4a06afda1180695b. However, backend django is  not working. backend_container is not working. Here is the error backend_container   | exec /app/entrypoint.sh: permission denied

Comment: I created a branch that has your code changes. you could review if its correct. I even tried to give permission like this: RUN chmod +x /app/entrypoint.sh but it doesnt help. https://github.com/axilaris/dockerize-django-react-celery-redis/tree/test1

Comment: i dont have this issue apprently !

Comment: i dont have this issue apprently!
its working fine for me localhost:8000/admin is working fine
you can try giving ownership to whole folder
try before dir 'RUN chmod -R +x  /app'

Comment: It doesnt work. i tried 'RUN chmod -R +x /app' and also tried another way https://forums.docker.com/t/entrypoint-sh-permission-denied-issue/91473 docker-compose build --no-cache. How did you get it work, did you use the same docker-compose build /  docker-compose up ? is there a way to troubleshoot this ? changing CMD back then backend_container works. Can I see your logs ? this is my logs https://gist.github.com/axilaris/5f365fdc8d341e92508848665d24e48d. Not sure if it helps, I'm using MacOS Sanoma 14.0

Comment: try what permissions entrypoint has by 
"ls -l entrypoint.sh" 
to know the rights
it should be 
-rwxr-xr-x

Comment: I tried "RUN ls -l entrypoint.sh" or "RUN ls -l /app/entrypoint.sh", there is nothing shown in the logs. Can you describe how to troubleshoot ?

Comment: oh, on the filesystem itself. I changed % chmod 755 entrypoint.sh. and it works!

Comment: do you think you can explain why it worked your changes ? it would be helpful to understand. why .:/django DIDNT work and this WORK - ./backend:/app ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257241/discussion-between-sujay-s-badge-and-axil).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're looking for logo such Redis ASCII logo shown below in your terminal.

````
                _._                
           _.-``__ ''-._           
      _.-``    `.  `_.  ''-._      
  .-`` .-```.  ```\/    _.,_ ''-._ 
 (    '      ,       .-`  | `,    )
 |`-._`-...-` __...-.``-._|'` _.-'|
 |    `-._   `._    /     _.-'    |
  `-._    `-._  `-./  _.-'    _.-' 
 |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|
 |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |
  `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-' 
 |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|
 |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |
  `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-' 
      `-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'     
          `-._        _.-'         
              `-.__.-'
````

In any case, here's what I went through.

The full logs in your [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/axilaris/a2776fc8f39e53bbc93e0d7a4e0ba0f5) shows that Celery is functioning correctly, but it doesn't display the Celery logo because it's a background process.

#### Celery Functionality:

- celery container creation is successful
- celery starts the gunicorn worker ([2024-03-13 12:27:32 +0000] [10] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0).
- There are no errors related to Celery in the logs.

#### Missing Celery Logo:

Celery itself doesn't have a graphical user interface (GUI) that displays a logo. It operates in the background, handling tasks asynchronously.

#### Background Task Logs:

The logs show successful execution of background tasks is likely because result.ready returns.

#### Debug Logs:

I see you enabled debugging mode in your `docker-compose.yaml` file and recommend to check the celery logs `docker-compose logs celery --tail=1000 -f` in order to check any missing logs.

Please let me know what you expect to see such as svg logo or ASCII logs if something I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that on some machines i could only start celery if i provide also name of worker, scheduller, queue and concurrency, try to run celery as follows:

```bash
celery worker -A backend --loglevel=info --concurrency=4 -n backend@localhost -Q backend -E -Ofair -B -s backend_schedule
```

also don't forget to configure celery at start like this:

```py
django.setup()
broker = CELERY_BROKER_URL
backend = CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND
app = Celery('backend')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.conf.broker_url = broker
app.conf.result_backend = backend
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

probably `CELERY_BROKER_URL` && `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND` you should set from env variables, in my case i set them in settings file.

Also it might be helpful to attach you image by id and try to start celery from cli.